# How do you generate an automatic click on a div without having an ID for it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a bit of an odd question. How could you generate an automatic click on a div, which I am obtaining from C#, via javascript without having an ID for that div? As a rough idea, what I am trying to do is the following (in layman's terms):

1. From C# side I am parsing the html document and locating the actual div that I need. Example div class="CLASSNAME">CONTENT /div
2. I need to pass this div somehow to a javascript function from the code-behind
   Example Page.RegisterStartupScript("myScript", FUNCTION_NAME(DIV_HTML);
3. In javascript generate an automatic click on this div element which I have just passed

I somehow cannot understand how the javascript function could generate a click on the div by having the HTML of this div as a parameter. Any ideas please guys?

Much thanks,
Jean

Comment: Why a click?  Why not just call your js function directly from the RegisterStartupScript code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It looks like there is a better way to do that.

Comment: I need to create a click because I am building a scraper and do not have access to the code that generates the HTML after the click

Answer (score 0):

Event is never automatic, when it is automatic, it is not an event. If you want to call some function, just call it at the right place. For example:

```
someElement.click(function(){
   ...
});
```

If you want it automatic,just call the function in the {}, replace it with:

```
this.doSomething=function(){
   ...
}
```

And call function doSomething() at the right place. 
So you can directly call the function after register the script, there is no need to fire a click event.

Comment: I need to create a click because I am building a scraper and do not have access to the code that generates the HTML after the click

Comment: Still a little confused, but if you use jquery, you can get the div by class name, or other attributes if it have.

Comment: yes I can get the div by class name or inner content but then I would have to go through the entire document every time to look for it and this will cost alot of time (I have to do it repeatedly)...I would like to get the div without looking in the entire document every time...maybe I can give it an outer DIV and look in there only?

Comment: That's another problem, you can use "var element=$(".className")" at the first time to get the div, and next time you access the div through element variable, you don't need to find it every time.